# Azure MySql Rest API . Inserting new firewall rule

Tags: mysql, rest, api, azure, firewall

I'm trying to create new Firewall rule. I have no problems updating existing rules but i can't create new. I'm getting true statusCode in response but can't see result in Azure portal (after few minutes). The code attached belongs to a Web App with propietary role to the MySql group resource. What i'm doing wrong?

```
private static string URI_FIREWALL_BASE = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/MY_RESOURCE/providers/Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers/MYSERVER/firewallRules/";

public string AddIPFirewallRule(string email, string IP)
    {
        AuthenticationResult token = AsyncContext.Run(() => AzureActiveDirectory.GetS2SAccessTokenForProdMSAAsync());
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AccessToken);

        JObject NewRule =
            new JObject(
            new JProperty("properties",
                new JObject(
                    new JProperty("startIpAddress", IP),
                    new JProperty("endIpAddress", IP)
                    )));

        var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NewRule);
        var httpContent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); 

        HttpResponseMessage resp = AsyncContext.Run(() => client.PutAsync(URI_FIREWALL_BASE + $"{email}?api-version=2017-12-01", httpContent));
        return AsyncContext.Run(() => resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
```

Comment: Finally i got it. I have to follow some rules to name the new service as you can see doing the same manually at Azure Portal Desktop.

Comment: You could post your comment as an answer to help others to find, thanks.

Comment: The REST API documentation for Azure DB for MySQL firewall rules is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/mysql/firewallrules/createorupdate

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it. I have to follow some rules to name the new service as you can see doing the same manually at Azure Portal Desktop.